# Ruby on Rails Active Record associations assistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to get some suggestions on my Active Record associations.

I want to make sure they’re setup in such a way that I can efficiently call the data needed.

**Models:**

- Users
- Scripts
- Commits

---

- Users can create scripts, which belong to them.
- Then, any user can add commits to any script.

**Associations:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scripts
  has_many :commits
  has_many :scripts, through: :commits
end

class Script < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commits
  has_many :users, through: :commits
end

class Commit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :script
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Some queries I’d like to be able to do:**

- A user can see all scripts that belong to them
- A user can see commits made to a particular script of theirs, and all commits across all their scripts
- Users can see commits they’ve made to a particular script, and all commits they’ve made

Hope I explained this clearly enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're modeling here, the relationship between `User` and `Script` should model ownership, and the indirect relationship through `Commit` is for contributions.  Assuming that's the case, you could add a little more meaning to the relationship names like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scripts
  has_many :commits
  has_many :contributed_scripts, through: :commits, source: :scripts
end

class Script < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commits
end

class Commit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :script
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Right. One user owns the script, and multiple users can make commits, I'd call them script-users.

Would Steve's answer accomplish the same relation, just different convention?

Thanks for taking the time to reply, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scripts
  has_many :commits, through: :scripts
end

class Script < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commits
end

class Commit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :script
  belongs_to :user
end
```

- This is enough

Answer (score 1):

Just make the role distinctions clear I'd suggest you do...

```
class Script < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commits
  has_many :contributors, through: :commits, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: Would Chris' answer accomplish the same relation, just different convention?
I'm leaning towards this, as it seems to make more sense logically/in English. Instead of 'contributors', I'd refer to them as 'script_users'. So something like: "A script has many script_users" sounds right!

Thanks for taking the time to reply, appreciate it!

Comment: The answers are compatible and you may want to do both. The question I answer is is given a script, show me all who contributed? Chris answers given a user, show me all scripts he's contributed to?

Comment: Thanks again! Got things working out I wanted, and figured out a few more handy associations to make too